# Update data in form 2 without opening a new form2

Tags: c#, winforms, updates

I have 2 forms, From1 and Form2. By clicking a button an image is sent to Form2 to be shown in pictureBox at Form 2.

Everytime I click the button a new Form2 is opened and image is shown but this is not what I am after.

I want that just the image in pictureBox at Form2 get updated and only one Form2(that opened at first time) stays.

Here is my code in Form1:

```
Image<Bgr, byte> imResult =DrawMatches(imColor,Points1, imColorPrv,Points2,Indices, new Bgr(System.Drawing.Color.Yellow), new Bgr(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
Form2 frmDrawMatchPoints = new Form2(imResult);
frmDrawMatchPoints.Show();
```

Here is my code in Form2:

```
Image<Bgr, byte> imResult;
public Form2(Image<Bgr, byte> imResult)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.imResult = imResult;
}

private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    picBoxMatches.Image = imResult.ToBitmap();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a new method to Form2:

```
public UpdateImage(Image<Bgr, byte> imResult)
{
    this.imResult = imResult;
    picBoxMatches.Image = imResult.ToBitmap();
}
```

And then in Form1 you could do this:

```
private Form2 form2;   // Some private field

// Inside the event handler
if (form2 == null)
    form2 = new Form2(imResult);
else
    form2.UpdateImage(imResult);
```

Comment: In Form 1, for the first time form2 should be assigned somewhere:
form2 = new Form2(imResult);

otherwise at line " if( form2==null) " I get the error:
Error 4 Use of unassigned local variable

Comment: @farzinparsa As I pointed out in my code, form2 should be a field which implicitly gets set to null. This won't work if your form2 is a variable that's local to the method because it will lose its value as soon as the method ends.

Answer (score 1):

Put this to global scope

```
public Form2 frmDrawMatchPoints = new Form2();
```

Make new function in Form2 with same parameters to preview your picture

```
public void PreviewPicture(Image<Bgr, byte> imResult)
{
    this.imResult = imResult;
}
```

In Form1 you should to have only:

```
Image<Bgr, byte> imResult =DrawMatches(imColor,Points1, imColorPrv,Points2,Indices, new Bgr(System.Drawing.Color.Yellow), new Bgr(System.Drawing.Color.Red);

frmDrawMatchPoints.PreviewPicture(imResult);
frmDrawMatchPoints.Show();
```